# Discord bot is not running for some reason CLOSED

Tags: python, discord, bots, helper

I need help with my bot, I coded it all before but then something happened and I made a new one and it just isn’t working when I run the code it works fine but the bot isn’t  online or responding to the commands

```py
import discord 
from keep_alive import keep_alive 

client = discord.Client() 

@client.event async def on_ready(): print('we have logged in as {0.user}').format.client

@client.event async def on_message(message): 
  
  
if message.author == client.user: return 

if message.content.startswith('$cmds'): 

await message.channel.send("Hello! how are you, my current commands are $cmds and $ping more coming soon!") keep_alive() client.run(os.getenv("Token"))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WipaM.jpg)

[enter image description here][2]

[2]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/URmvr.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URmvr.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei20c.jpg)

Comment: Can you please send your code and error here?

Comment: There is none it says it’s all logged in but it hasn’t

Comment: Please send the code here, edit your question and paste the code you have

Comment: Ok it’s there now

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you use the commands framework :-

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@client.command()
async def cmds(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Hello! how are you, my current commands are $cmds and $ping more coming soon!")
```

Comment: Can you help me with the whole code please like the up time bot commands and stuff?

Comment: Uh I cannot tbh. You can go through the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)or watch some yt tutorials

Comment: It just says this when I run the code (look in the original question)

Comment: It means you have the wrong token, insert the correct token from the [discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro)